# How to create beautiful (block) diagrams

Tags: information-graphics, information-design, diagram, data-visualisation

I would like to include a similar picture in my bachelor's thesis.

I am looking for tips on how to make this (or in general) diagram(s) more beautiful.

Can you recommend programs for creating such diagrams? Preferably free and runs under Linux.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to the exchange. A bunch of questions exist on this topic. Here is one that I think you'll find most valuable: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16629/drawing-block-diagram?rq=1 ---- you can also click on tags such as `diagram` in your question or `information-graphics` in the one I linked to see more questions about the topic.

Comment: For the "tips on how to make it beautiful" side of the question, you might find **[Examples of well designed software architecture diagrams](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15788/examples-of-well-designed-software-architecture-diagrams)** useful - this isn't software architecture but the type of diagram is similar.

Comment: Another link is: [Flow chart software for Linux](http://superuser.com/questions/209999/flow-chart-software-for-linux)

Comment: You can take a look at TikZ. You rather program your graphics, but they sure look great (I think).